# Getting rep(0, x) in combination with data.table in R order to create leading zeros (invalid times argument)

Tags: r

I created the following data.table as an example:

```
dt <- data.table(x = c(1, 12, 200, 1600))
dt[, y := " "]
```

My goal is to fill the *y* column with the x values extended by leading zeros such that each entry in *y* consists of four digits (i.e. 0001, 0012, 0200, 1600).

My idea is as follows:

```
dt[, y := x] # fill column with original values
dt[nchar(as.integer(x)) < 4, y := paste(paste(rep(0, 4-nchar(as.integer(x))), collapse=""), x, sep="")]
```

This command is supposed to check whether *x* consists of less than 4 digits, and, if so, generate the required number of zeros and paste them at the beginning of the string. Executing the statement however yields the message "**Error in rep(0, 4 - nchar(as.integer(x))) : invalid 'times' argument**".

I know that my basic idea is correct since the following command works properly:

```
dt[nchar(as.integer(x)) < 4, y := paste(paste(rep(0, 4), collapse=""), x, sep="")]
```

Here, I simply replaced the second argument in rep() by a random number (4 in this case).

Therefore, rep() obviously has some problems understanding the column reference made by *x*. Other functions (e.g. as.numeric() and many many more) don't have problems with this.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Look into sprintf.

Answer (score 1):

Juse use `formatC`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x = c(1, 12, 200, 1600))
dt[, y := formatC(x, width = 6, format = "d", flag = "0")] #
dt

      x      y
1:    1 000001
2:   12 000012
3:  200 000200
4: 1600 001600
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're feeding rep() a vector of length>1.

There are probably formats you can use? Below is a workaround step-by-step.

```
dt <- data.frame(x = c(1, 12, 200, 1600))

dt$times_to_rep<-4-nchar(dt$x)
dt$power_of_ten<-10^dt$times_to_rep
dt$zeros<-substring(dt$power_of_ten,2,nchar(dt$power_of_ten))
dt$y<-paste0(dt$zeros, dt$x, sep = '')
```